# rke Error: snapshot missing hash but --skip-hash-check=false

Tags: rke

I'm trying to restore an etcd snapshot after a power outage but I'm getting the following error.

```
FATA[0020] [etcd] Failed to restore etcd snapshot: Failed to run etcd restore container, exit status is: 128, container logs: Error: snapshot missing hash but --skip-hash-check=false
```

I'm running `rke etcd snapshot-restore --config rancher-cluster.yaml --name 202008091207.zip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is caused by the incorrect inclusion of the .zip file extension to the snapshot name parameter.

The snapshot name parameter (--name) should contain the snapshot name, excluding the file extension.

Please try the following command.

```
rke etcd snapshot-restore --config rancher-cluster.yaml --name 202008091207
```